# MVC 5 routing with GUID as id, hide in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm using VS2013 Preview on W8.1 under project MVC 5 (.NET 4.5 not 4.5.1) and I've been researching for the past few hours trying all sorts of things and it seems I just don't get what I'm missing.

I'm working on a school project by building a forum and I want the URL to be hierarchical, i.e.
`localhost:1234/Forum/Science/Physics/String%20Theory`.

This is the RouteConfig:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{action}/{*title}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", title = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Categories.Where(x => x.ParentId == null).ToList());
    }

public ActionResult Forum(string parentId)
    {
        return View("Index", db.Categories.Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId));
    }
```

And view (which is the index page):

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="CatLevel0">
            <h2>@Ajax.ActionLink(item.Title, "Forum", new { parentId = item.Id, title = item.Title }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" })</h2>
            <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</h4>
        </div>
    }
```

Herein lies the problem. The link above (e.g. "Science") directs to:
`"http://localhost:1234/Forum/Science?parentId=b8bd9ded-7284-462d-b0cc-d8ce09717b8a"`,
and the 2nd level after being forwarded to "Science" and being redirected to "Social Sciences" I get:
`"http://localhost:1234/Forum/Social%20Sciences?parentId=2a9f1c24-c6d4-44ab-b000-3268f38794f3"`.

So not only do I get the redundant GUID in the querystring (which I don't want!), but I also lose the precursor "Science" in "~/Forum/Science/Social%20Sciences";

In a few other SO questions it was noted that Ajax.ActionLink requires jquery unobtrusive ajax, it renders correctly on my end judging by the network tab in Chrome Developer Tools.

**Update**: I managed to fix the issue @TimothyWalters mentioned, using the following:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Forum(string parentId, string title)
    {
        TempData["fullTitle"] = title + "/";
        return View("Index", db.Categories.Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId));
    }
```

View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="CatLevel0">
            @*<h2>@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Forum", new { parentId = item.Id, title = item.Title })</h2>*@
            <h2>@Ajax.ActionLink(item.Title, "Forum", new { parentId = item.Id, title = TempData["fullTitle"] + item.Title }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" })</h2>
            <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</h4>
        </div>
    }
```

So now I have `http://localhost:5465/Forum/Science/Social%20Sciences?parentId=2a9f1c24-c6d4-44ab-b000-3268f38794f3`, which leaves the issue of the GUID in querystring to be handled.

**Update2**:Ugh - now I get this: `http://localhost:5465/Forum/Science/Social%20Sciences/Science/Social%20Sciences?parentId=2a9f1c24-c6d4-44ab-b000-3268f38794f3` . . . .

Comment: How many levels do you want? Note that the `{*title}` in your route (with the asterisk) means "everything after `{action}/` should be passed to the action method in a `title` parameter". So your code is not taking that into account.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, I'm aiming for unlimited levels.
And I'm not entirely sure what you mean, what should I do to make the method take that into account?

Comment: @AgonEous I believe what he means is that `Science/Physics/String Theory` will be assigned to the `title` parameter. It will be up to you to work out your hierarchy from that.

Comment: @TimothyWalters, how would I go about 'working out' my hierarchy? And "Science/Physics/String Theory" isn't assigned to title, but only the "String Theory".

Comment: @AgonEous if you were getting the full hierarchy in the string then you could split on '/' and rebuild that way (find level with null parentID that matches "Science", find child that matches "Physics" etc). If the title is only picking up the last part then that isn't going to work though. Since `{action}` is "Forum", I'd like to know where the other parts of the path have gone.

Comment: @TimothyWalters, updated the question. The issue of only the last title part being used is resolved. Thanks!
Now there's just the issue of the GUID in querystring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the GUID in the query string, stop putting it there. If you aren't going to have it there, you'll need some reliable way of extracting meaning from your path.

You are explicitly telling it to put the GUID in the query string with the code in your view where you include `parentId` in your call to `ActionLink()`. Remove that parameter and you won't have a GUID there anymore.

To extract meaning from your path, you need a way to turn "Science/Physics/String Theory" into the "String Theory" child of the parent you previously found by GUID.

```
var parts = title.Split('/');
var categories = db.Categories
    .Where(c => parts.Contains(c.Title))
    .ToList();

// start at the root
var category = categories.Where(c => c.ParentId == null && c.Title == parts[0]);

// look for anything past the root level (starting at index 1 not 0)
for (var i = 1; i < parts.Length; i++)
{
    category = categories.Where(c => c.ParentId == category.Id && c.Title == parts[i]);
}

// use category to create new view
return View(category);
```

Comment: My only concern about that is that the GUID is the unique identifier, on the other hand, should I have two categories with the same name, even if under different parents, it could be a potential problem in the future.

I do wonder if a @Html.BeginForm() could be used here to do a post submit so it would be in the body of the request and not in the URL.

Comment: @AgonEous yes, I simply tried to provide what you asked for, a route that allows you to have the full path without the GUID. You could hide this in the form and do a post, but it would be pointless having the path in the URL in that case as it wouldn't do anything really, other than tricking users into bookmarking a sub-forum and the bookmark not working since it wouldn't have the GUID being posted in the hidden form field.

Comment: so am I to take it that I have no choice but make the titles become unique and drop the usage of GUIDs with categories?

Comment: If you want to allow people to bookmark a page with a nice URL like "/Forums/Science/Physics/String Theory" then yes, a GUID isn't going to help you there. Also the title only needs to be unique under that parent, you could have "Science/Physics" and "Biology/Physics" without any issues. The other option is to make the path cosmetic and include the GUID in the URL, e.g. "Science/Physics/String Theory/?id=2a9f1c24-c6d4-44ab-b000-3268f38794f3", you would ignore the path and just use the ID to find the right forum.

Comment: I see. That is highly unfortunate. But if there's no choice I guess I'll just have to live with it. Thank you for your help.